# Running JavaFX 2 on Mac with Java 6?

Tags: java, macos, deployment, javafx

I'm developing a Java Swing application using some features of JavaFX 2(such as WebBrowser).

I tried to reference the jfxrt.jar file from inside my folders, since it seems that a javaFX2 installer for MAC is not available (only installing Java 7).
But I would like to use JavaFX 2 also with Java 6.

I get this error:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: getScaleFactor
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.initFx(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javabrowser.JpJavaBrowser.initComponentsFx(JpJavaBrowser.java:63)
    at javabrowser.JpJavaBrowser.<init>(JpJavaBrowser.java:59)
    at orderbook.FrOrderBook.initComponents(FrOrderBook.java:625)
    at orderbook.FrOrderBook.<init>(FrOrderBook.java:179)
    at orderbook.FrOrderBook$2.run(FrOrderBook.java:681)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        ...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: getScaleFactor
    at com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacApplication._initIDs(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacApplication.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacPlatformFactory.createApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.Run(Unknown Source)
    ... 23 more
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX 2 does not support Java6 on OS-X - Java6 is only supported on win32